# How to sum the digits of a number using Recursion [C]?

Tags: c, recursion, sum, digits

For instance , the number is 123, the answer is 6. Only recursion!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We like to help, but we want to see you make an attempt first. What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While @SamGrondahl is on the right track, unfortunately, if you enter a negative number it gives unexpected results. This should work properly with negative numbers:

```
int sumdigits(int number) {
    int sign = number < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    number = sign * number; // abs the number

    if (number < 10) 
        return sign * number;
    else 
        return sign * (number % 10 + sumdigits(number / 10));
}
```

This will return the sum of the digits, and if the number is negative, negate that.

Answer (score 1):

A correct answer is trickier to achieve than at first glance, since the negation of `INT_MIN` may not fit in an `int`. The posted solutions would work for the most part by changing their implementation to use `unsigned int` during recursion. Below is an alternative to that.

```
int sum_digits_recursively (char digits[], int i) {
    if (i == 0 && digits[i] == '-') return -sum_digits_recursively(digits, 1);
    if (digits[i] == '\0') return 0;
    return (digits[i]-'0') + sum_digits_recursively(digits, i+1);
}

int sum_digits (int x) {
    char digits[sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT];
    snprintf(digits, sizeof(digits), "%d", x);
    return sum_digits_recursively(digits, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you want:

```
int recurse( int number ) {
    if ( abs(number) < 10 ) return number;
    return number % 10 + recurse ( number / 10 );
}
```

Comment: What if the number is negative? Gives unexpected results then.

Comment: Why would you sum the digits of a negative number?

Comment: Taking it to an absolute value doesn't change anything.  If the number was -213, I would expect 2, not 6.

Comment: No, you would expect -6. The negative operator applies to all trailing digits. Otherwise -213 would mean -200 + 10 + 3.

Comment: @MichaelBurr:  I wouldn't expect -6 from -213.  I wish to transform -213 into -2+1+3 instead.  It just means that the highest order value could detract from your overall sum.  There is a way to do that.

Comment: humm, whats the meaning of abs? also i only need it for positive numbers so Sam's answer is useful!

Comment: int abs ( int number ) { int result = number < 0 ? -1 * number : number; return result }

Comment: @GonzaloAntonicelli abs means `absolute value`. His answer is still incorrect for negative numbers, though.

Comment: Exactly: "@MichaelBurr: I wouldn't expect -6 from -213. I wish to transform -213 into -2+1+3 instead. It just means that the highest order value could detract from your overall sum. There is a way to do that." Doesn't make sense to me, but perhaps the right way in any case.